# How to queue post request using workbox?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, background-sync, workbox

Using following js in my service worker from [workboxjs sample](https://workboxjs.org/examples/workbox-sw/) for my testing:

```
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/workbox-sw@0.0.2/build/importScripts/workbox-sw.dev.v0.0.2.js');
```

I want to try out how to queue the post requests in offline mode using workbox-sw, so once the network is available it process the request from the queue!

**Q 1:**
I think I need to import additional libraries to define my routes for post methods as shown here on github [issue #634](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/634)

How can use import on browser? I tried using `importScripts` but it doesn't work.

```
import * as worker from 'workbox-sw';
import 'workbox-routing';
```

**Q 2:**
Do I need any additional libraries for background sync, so post methods are queued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using it as part of the larger `workbox-sw` framework, as a plugin. Here's a version of the sample code, modified to use `importScripts()` to pull in the Workbox code from a CDN. Alternatively, rather than using the pre-packaged bundles over a CDN, you could use the ES2015 module syntax and then a bundler like Rollup or Webpack to include the relevant code from your local `node_modules` into the final service worker file.

```
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/workbox-runtime-caching@1.3.0');
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/workbox-routing@1.3.0');
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/workbox-background-sync@1.3.0');

let bgQueue = new workbox.backgroundSync.QueuePlugin({
  callbacks: {
    replayDidSucceed: async(hash, res) => {
      self.registration.showNotification('Background sync demo', {
        body: 'Product has been purchased.',
        icon: '/images/shop-icon-384.png',
       });
    },
    replayDidFail: (hash) => {},
    requestWillEnqueue: (reqData) => {},
    requestWillDequeue: (reqData) => {},
  },
});

const requestWrapper = new workbox.runtimeCaching.RequestWrapper({
  plugins: [bgQueue],
});

const route = new workbox.routing.RegExpRoute({
  regExp: new RegExp('^https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'),
  handler: new workbox.runtimeCaching.NetworkOnly({requestWrapper}),
});

const router = new workbox.routing.Router();
router.registerRoute({route});
```